# Adding video to ArcGIS API for JavaScript popup template?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup, infowindow, video

I was wondering how do I add a video to be played in the popup template?

I've looked at the documentation here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_extendInfowindow.html

and can't seem to find any information on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of the `getTextContent` function in that sample shows how an infoWindow can contain HTML:

```
return "<b>" + commName + "</b><br /><a target='_blank' href=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + sciName  +">Wikipedia Entry</a>";
```

You can set this using [infoWindow.setContent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/infowindow-amd.html#setcontent), and point to the location of the video.

From this point you can use standard [HTML video](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) tags, or the embed link from YouTube, Vimeo, etc.

Comment: Does this work for PopupTemplate as well? I'm actually using PopupTemplate. I find that when I'm trying to set title by doing this it doesn't work: `code` var popupTemplate = PopupTemplate();

    popupTemplate.setTitle("<h2>YOLO</h2>");

    popupTemplate.setContent(loadVideo);
    popupTemplate.setContent("<div><p>Testing 123</p></div>");`/code`

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't work"? What happens with your second example, with the Testing 123?

Comment: My apologies. What I meant is that it only displays the last thing I set to it (i.e. test 123). The setContent(loadVideo) does not call on the function loadVideo, and the setTitle does not set the title. I was hoping to be able to set a bunch of fieldsInfos to it, and then load a video at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this...

```
//works Template            
        var template  = new PopupTemplate();    
        template.setTitle("<b>Works Point</b>");        
        template.setContent(getContent); //this will call the getContent function where you can custom build your fields and add video


function getContent(graphic){   
Content = "Project Name:" + graphic.attributes.NAME + "<br> Prov:" + graphic.attributes.PROV;                          

Hyperlink = "Hyperlink: <a href='http://www.youtube.com'>Project Link</a>"

return Content + Hyperlink;
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your answer! I was wondering how would I be able to still use fieldInfos[] with the setContent() method? 
This link uses fieldInfos, but I don't see them ever using them together? https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/popuptemplate.html
and when I tried to use them together the fieldInfos never showed?

Comment: I'm not sure. Why do you need the fieldInfos?